# How to lock Xeon cpu frequency to a specific clock rate?

Tags: cpu, cpu-load, cpufreq, frequency

So I am using a Xeon 2620 v4 through ssh/command line only. I have sudo access and have set all CPU governor to performance mode.

However, when I set the frequency using: `"sudo cpufreq-set -f 2100"` the clock speed of each CPU core is all over the places. Some gets 1.3ghz, some 1.9, some 2.5 3.0, ...

Is there anyway to set one frequency for them all?

Comment: Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1256619/problem-with-fixed-frequencies-using-cpufreq-gnome-extension/1256628#1256628) answer your question? The performance governor with an HWP (HardWare P-state) capable processor (which you have, I think) should be stable enough for any applications, as it will settle quickly to the requested max CPU frequency. You can use percent to set the max freq: example: `echo 70 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct`. You can set 2.1 GHz as max by disabling turbo.

Comment: I have the error "/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo: No such file or directory
1" when I type "echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo". Or error " tee: /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo: No such file or directory
"

Comment: Oh. Are you not running the default intel_pstate CPU frequency scaling driver? Do: `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver`

Comment: The answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/619875/disabling-intel-turbo-boost-in-ubuntu/620114#620114) cover both methods of disabling turbo, one (mine) for intel_pstate, and one for acpi-cpufreq.

Comment: the command you gave me show "scaling_driver: pcc-cpufreq" at the end. What does that mean?

Comment: "echo "0" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/boost" I used this and got permission deny. I guess I have to go ask the admin

Comment: I am not familiar with the pcc-cpufreq CPU frequency scaling driver, nor why your system would be using it. You could override it and load one of the others via grub command line, I think. see also [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/pcc-cpufreq.txt)

Comment: Thank you it works! Can you write an answer so that I can mark it as correct?

Comment: I wrote an answer then deleted it, because [this reference](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.8/admin-guide/pm/intel_pstate.html) says using intel_pstate=force should not work with pcc-cpufreq.

Comment: Ah I have found a way to change the driver to intel_pstate. That's why it worked. So your answer is correct

Comment: Then just upvote the answers I referred you to.