# Disabling CPU frequency scaling Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, performance, cpu, scaling

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, and following [this tutorial](https://frankaemika.github.io/docs/troubleshooting.html#disable-cpu-frequency-scaling) to disable CPU frequency scaling.

I have done:

```
sudo systemctl disable ondemand
sudo systemctl enable cpufrequtils
sudo sh -c 'echo "GOVERNOR=performance" > /etc/default/cpufrequtils'
sudo systemctl daemon-reload && sudo systemctl restart cpufrequtils
```

then **reboot** then I have checked the state of the `GOVERNOR` for each cpu `0-->11` and I see the mode as `performance`, now when I check using `$ cpufreq-info` I get:

```
analyzing CPU 11:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 11
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 11
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 4.10 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 4.10 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 800 MHz.
```

Same for all CPUs from `0 --> 11`, can you please tell me how can I disable CPU frequency scaling correctly? thanks in advance.

Comment: Even with the `performance` CPU frequency scaling governor, that processor can reduce the frequency from maximum if the load is light enough. If you have significant load on some CPUs and are still getting 800 MHz, then that is not expected.

Comment: @DougSmythies but what I expect after following [that tutorial](https://frankaemika.github.io/docs/troubleshooting.html#disable-cpu-frequency-scaling) is to have my cpu running at full scale frequency all the time

Comment: It is unusual to observe the minimum CPU frequency with the `performance` CPU frequency scaling governor. If you really want the CPUs to always be running at the maximum frequency all the time, then you need to disable all idle states, at a huge cost in power.

Comment: see also [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1256619/problem-with-fixed-frequencies-using-cpufreq-gnome-extension/1256628#1256628). What is your Intel processor model? Do: `grep -m 1 "model name" /proc/cpuinfo`